# How to fix height of a table - Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic-ui-react but I'm also open to answers specific to semantic-ui.

I'm having a paginated table, but there's a problem. The last page which can have fewer rows takes a different height. I'd like to know how I can fix the height of the table.

My code is very simple:

```
  <Table singleLine>
    <TableHeader data={ entities } columns={ columns }/>
    <Table.Body>
      { tableBody }
    </Table.Body>
    { paginator }
  </Table>
```

`TableHeader` is:

```
  <Table.Header>
    <Table.Row>
      {
        _.map(columns, column => {
          return <Table.HeaderCell>{ column(data) }</Table.HeaderCell>;
        })
      }
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Header>
```

`tableBody` is:

```
  for (let index = pageSize * pageIndex; index < Math.min(pageSize * (pageIndex + 1), entities.length); index++) {
    tableBody.push(<TableRow data={ entities[index] } rowConfig={ rowConfig }/>);
  }
```

and `tableRow` is:

```
  <Table.Row>
    {
      _.map(rowConfig, cellConfig => {
        return <Table.Cell>{ cellConfig(data) }</Table.Cell>;
      })
    }
  </Table.Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem, why don't you just use a css class with a min-height on the component, like this

```
.min-height {
    min-height:397px;
}
```

Comment: It'll violate the responsiveness of my design.